# Ruby ODBC noscan

Tags: sql, ruby, odbc, sanitization

I am trying to insert a value into sql db through ruby. I am using ruby 2.0 and ruby-odbc 0.99995.

I am having an issue sanitizing the input. I tried setting `noscan` to `true` and `false`. It still throws an error.

```
str = "some'ss"
query = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( col_name1) VALUES (#{str})"
conn = ODBC.connect(@odbc,@user,@pw)  
stmt = conn.prepare(query)
stmt.noscan = false
stmt.execute
conn.disconnect
```

How to sanitize the query string? I hope there is an inbuilt method in ODBC

Here the string str apostrophe to be inserted.

Comment: You are not sanitizing input at all. You are using Ruby string interpolation, not prepared statement parametrisation. You should have `query = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( col_name1) VALUES (?)"` and `stmt.execute(str)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amadan mentioned in the comments. Try using a prepared statement.

```
str = "some'ss"
query = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( col_name1) VALUES (?), str"
conn = ODBC.connect(@odbc,@user,@pw)  
stmt = conn.prepare(query)
stmt.noscan = false
stmt.execute
conn.disconnect
```